# Java thread synchronization gives weird output

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, wait

My aim is to print odd numbers by one thread and even numbers by another thread.
Below implementation shows weird output. Please let me know what I am missing in this code.

It prints 0 and 1 as expected. Then it prints 3 and 2.

// Expected  - > 012345678910

// Actual output by this code  - > 013254769810 (Flow is changing)

```
public class OddEvenNumberPrint {
    public static boolean state = false; // based on this flag I will wait or notify
    public static Object lock = new Object(); // the common locking object
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvenThread t1 = new EvenThread("Even");
        t1.start();
        OddThread t2 = new OddThread("Odd");
        t2.start();

    }

}

class EvenThread extends Thread {
    

    public EvenThread(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
            synchronized (OddEvenNumberPrint.lock) {
                System.out.println("Even ->"+i);
                while (!OddEvenNumberPrint.state) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " : "+ "Going wait");
                        OddEvenNumberPrint.lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                OddEvenNumberPrint.state = false;
                OddEvenNumberPrint.lock.notify();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " : "+ "Released");

            }
        }

    }
}

class OddThread extends Thread {
    

    public OddThread(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 2) {
            synchronized (OddEvenNumberPrint.lock) {
                System.out.println("Odd -> "+i);
                while (OddEvenNumberPrint.state) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " : "+ "Going wait");
                        OddEvenNumberPrint.lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                OddEvenNumberPrint.state = true;
                OddEvenNumberPrint.lock.notify();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " : "+ "Released");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Even ->0
Even : Going wait
Odd -> 1
Odd : Released
Odd -> 3
Odd : Going wait
Even : Released
Even ->2
Even : Going wait
Odd : Released
Odd -> 5
Odd : Going wait
Even : Released
Even ->4
Even : Going wait
Odd : Released
Odd -> 7
Odd : Going wait
Even : Released
Even ->6
Even : Going wait
Odd : Released
Odd -> 9
Odd : Going wait
Even : Released
Even ->8
Even : Going wait
Odd : Released
Even : Released
Even ->10
Even : Going wait
```

Comment: Please explain what you consider "weird" about the output, and what your reasoning is for considering it weird. Also explain what you expected instead.

Comment: What output did you expect ?!!

Comment: 1. hint: your program doesn't terminate. (within an acceptable period) 2. hint: don't use local variable for counting, but a "synchronized" one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and Omid,  I have given the proper details.

Comment: @xerx593, termination is not an issue for me. The order matters. I am not seeing any problem with using local variable for counting.

Comment: Nothing prevents the odd loop from printing 1 and then printing 3 before the even thread gets its turn again. If you want the order you expect, you probably need to initialize `state` to true, and move the printing of the value until **after** the loop (though I haven't looked to closely). You seem to expect that `notify()` will immediately give the other thread a chance to run, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Considering:

0. Because `even` thread is created and started before `odd` thread, so it **doesn't** mean `even` surely will acquire lock of mutex(`lock`) first, NO! `odd` has its chance to acquire it before `even` too. So possible to have `1` and then `0`
1. State management is the key in multi-threading, where your problem sits on it. Signaling must be done at right time/point.

**The Problem**

The problem with your code is signaling and state-management at wrong points, specially the start point for both threads look buggy.

Let's simulate the run:
Assuming `even` thread get started and acquire that `lock` first.
time 0. `even` thread prints 0

```
             |Even Thread              |Odd Thread               |lock/mutex
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 0       |acquires lock of mutex   |blocked, cannot acquire  |false
             |                         |lock of mutex            |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 1       |prints (next even 0,...) |still waiting...         |false
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 2       |going to unlock mutex    |acquires lock of mutex   |false
             |and wait for a signal    |as it's unlocked from    |
             |becasue lock == false    |even                     |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 3       |still waiting...         |prints (next odd 1,...)  |false
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 4       |still waiting...         |won't wait for a signal  |false
             |                         |since lock is false      |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 5       |still waiting...         |set the lock state to    |true
             |                         |true                     |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 6       |still waiting...         |notify on mutex, but     |true            
             |Got one signal on mutex  |WON'T unlock it yet      |
             |but CANNOT continue as   |                         |
             |it's not release yet     |                         |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 7       |Can get lock of mutext   |one loop has finished    |true            
             |as odd released it       |now try to acquire the   |
             |now can continue         |mutex again, but cannot  |
             |                         |since it just got locked |
             |                         |by even thread           |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 8       |set the lock state to    |still waiting...         |false           
             |false                    |                         |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 9       |notify on mutex, but     |still waiting...         |false           
             |WON'T unlock it yet      |Got one signal on mutex  |
             |                         |but CANNOT continue as   |
             |                         |it's not release yet     |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 10      |one loop has finished    |Can get lock of mutext   |false           
             |now try to acquire the   |as even released it      |
             |mutex again, but cannot  |now can continue         |
             |since it just got locked |                         |
             |by odd thread            |                         |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 11      |still waiting...         |prints (next odd 3)      |false
             |to acquire lock, not a   |                         |
             |signal                   |                         |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
time 12      |still waiting...         |won't wait for a signal  |false
             |                         |since lock is false      |
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------
....
```

Please mind `time 3`, and `time 11`, that's because 1, then 3. Since `even` thread has no chance to print `2`.

Now thinking, that `odd` thread get started first before `even`?

**Hint:** If thread `B` must be started essentially after thread `A`, the robust way is starting the thread `B` from thread `A`